# What layer should resolve pre-existing Hibernate entities?

Tags: object-oriented-design, orm, architectural-patterns

Imagine an application that consumes an external data stream and creates objects of this type:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private EventInfo info;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private EventSource source;

  ...

}
```

Later in the DAO:

```
session.save(event);
```

In the data stream, every `Event` has a fully self-contained JSON representation of both the `EventInfo` and the `EventSource`.

This has been working fine, but now I need to refactor this code and ensure that `EventSource` entities are re-used, i.e. change to:

```
  @ManyToOne(cascade = ???)
  private EventSource source;
```

Now the question is this. Given that the external data-stream always contains a full representation, it is necessary to look-up `EventSource` in the database and re-set the value in the `Event` object prior to saving the `Event` entity.

What layer of the application should be responsible for the look-up?

Comment: I see the makings of a good question here, but I don't think there's quite enough information in your post to make it answerable.  You haven't told us anything about your architecture, and I don't know what "receiving application" means.  So I'm going to go ahead and close this and leave it on the site for a few days so that you can clarify it.

Comment: In the meantime, assuming your architecture is reasonably "typical" (if there is such a thing in software development), I see no reason why you couldn't do this in your Data Access Layer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I clarified the question by removing the word "receiving", as that seemed to imply two different applications were involved. There is only one application, and the architecture is described in the opening line: "Imagine an application that consumes an external data stream and creates objects of [given type]". I put a lot of thought into omitting unnecessary details. Is there anything else I can clarify? Thanks

Comment: What kind of architecture are you using?  Three-Tier?  Model-View-ViewModel?

Comment: basic Spring MVC with no complications

Comment: Is there a place in Spring where you can put customizations like this?

Comment: That's the heart of my question, keeping in mind that Spring is just a particular implementation of an MVC architecture.

Comment: Spring should have a "code-generated" model or somesuch for your data.  Your modification would go in the layer right above that.

Comment: Robert I appreciate your enthusiasm but it seems you're speculating about how Spring MVC works, and anyway my question is not about this particular implementation of MVC (if it was, I would post in a Spring forum). I'm asking about the appropriate place to do this in a standard MVC architecture, regardless of framework.

Comment: Same answer.  The layer right above your DAL.  The DAL should be "pure;" that is, it should be an exact reflection of your database.  As you already pointed out, this has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: The "The layer right above your DAL" is typically a Service Layer. Would you care to elaborate on why you believe this is the correct answer?

Comment: As I said, your DAL should be "pure."  It's probably not the best idea to put the modification there, and any other layer would be too high.  Yes, the Service Layer is uniquely suited; it is in the Service Layer that you provide business-level modifications to your data.

Comment: Thank you. Please feel free to submit your comments as an Answer.